# error C2664: cannot convert argument error

Tags: c++

I am getting following errors while compiling my code and build is not successful

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'DWORD GetCurrentDirectoryA(DWORD,LPSTR)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'wchar_t [260]' to 'LPSTR'  
Error   2   error C2664: 'BOOL SetCurrentDirectoryA(LPCSTR)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'wchar_t *' to 'LPCSTR'   
Error   3   error C2664: 'BOOL SetCurrentDirectoryA(LPCSTR)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'wchar_t [260]' to 'LPCSTR'   
Error   4   error C2664: 'HMODULE GetModuleHandleA(LPCSTR)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t [13]' to 'LPCSTR'
```

my cpp code

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

#include "native_library.h"

#undef UNICODE

#include <windows.h>


//#include "base/files/file_util.h"
//#include "base/strings/stringprintf.h"
//#include "base/strings/utf_string_conversions.h"
//#include "base/threading/thread_restrictions.h"

namespace base {

typedef HMODULE (WINAPI* LoadLibraryFunction)(const wchar_t* file_name);

namespace {

NativeLibrary LoadNativeLibraryHelper(const std::string& library_path,
                                      LoadLibraryFunction load_library_api,
                                      NativeLibraryLoadError* error) {
  // LoadLibrary() opens the file off disk.
  //ThreadRestrictions::AssertIOAllowed();

  // Switch the current directory to the library directory as the library
  // may have dependencies on DLLs in this directory.
  bool restore_directory = false;
  wchar_t current_directory[MAX_PATH];
  std::wstring lp = std::wstring(library_path.begin(), library_path.end());
  std::wstring plugin_path, plugin_value;
  if (GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,current_directory))
  {
    const wchar_t *res = wcsrchr(lp.c_str(), '\\');
    if (res)
    {
      plugin_path.assign(lp.c_str(),res);
      plugin_value.assign(++res, wcsrchr(res,0));
    }
    else
      plugin_value = lp;

    if (!plugin_path.empty())
    {
      SetCurrentDirectory((wchar_t*)plugin_path.c_str());
      restore_directory = true;
    }
  }

  HMODULE module = (*load_library_api)((wchar_t*)plugin_value.c_str());
  if (!module && error) {
    // GetLastError() needs to be called immediately after |load_library_api|.
    error->code = GetLastError();
  }

  if (restore_directory)
    SetCurrentDirectory(current_directory);

  return module;
}

}  // namespace

std::string NativeLibraryLoadError::ToString() const
{
    char buf[32];
    return int2char(code, buf);
}

// static
NativeLibrary LoadNativeLibrary(const std::string& library_path,
                                NativeLibraryLoadError* error) {
  return LoadNativeLibraryHelper(library_path, LoadLibraryW, error);
}

NativeLibrary LoadNativeLibraryDynamically(const std::string& library_path) {
  typedef HMODULE (WINAPI* LoadLibraryFunction)(const wchar_t* file_name);

  LoadLibraryFunction load_library;
  load_library = reinterpret_cast<LoadLibraryFunction>(
      GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW"));

  return LoadNativeLibraryHelper(library_path, load_library, NULL);
}

// static
void UnloadNativeLibrary(NativeLibrary library) {
  FreeLibrary(library);
}

// static
void* GetFunctionPointerFromNativeLibrary(NativeLibrary library,
                                          const char* name) {
  return GetProcAddress(library, name);
}

// static
//string16 GetNativeLibraryName(const string16& name) {
//  return name + ASCIIToUTF16(".dll");
//}

}  // namespace base
```

Kindly suggest what is wrong and how to fix this issue

Comment: The second argument to `GetCurrentDirectory()` is supposed to be `LPSTR`, but `current_directory` is an array of `wchar_t`.

Comment: Why do you have `#undef UNICODE`?  That's necessary to use the correct function calls for `wstring` in the Windows API.

Comment: What is wrong is that you "cannot convert argument 2 from 'wchar_t [260]' to 'LPSTR'", and you "cannot convert argument 1 from 'wchar_t *' to 'LPCSTR'"; furthermore you "cannot convert argument 1 from 'wchar_t [260]' to 'LPCSTR'", and finally you "cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t [13]' to 'LPCSTR'".

Comment: Seems like your application is targeted for ANSI, (#undef UNICODE).... you can not use wide characters

Answer (score 1):

The errors are self-explanatory.  You are passing `wchar_t` buffers/pointers where `char*` pointers are expected.  They are not compatible types.  Notice that all of the error messages indicate the `A`NSI versions of the API functions are being called.

DO NOT use `#undef UNICODE`!  It is not the code's responsibility to (un)define `UNICODE` (and `_UNICODE` for the C RTL).  It is the project's responsibility to handle that when invoking the compiler.

By undefining `UNICODE` manually, you are forcing all `TCHAR`-based Win32 API macros (like the ones you are calling) to map to ANSI versions instead of Unicode versions.

If you want to using ANSI strings, call the `A`NSI functions explicitly.  If you want to using Unicode strings, call the `W`ide functions explicitly.  Stop relying on `TCHAR` definitions.

Try this instead:

```
NativeLibrary LoadNativeLibraryHelper(const std::string& library_path,
                                      LoadLibraryFunction load_library_api,
                                      NativeLibraryLoadError* error) {
  // LoadLibrary() opens the file off disk.
  //ThreadRestrictions::AssertIOAllowed();

  // Switch the current directory to the library directory as the library
  // may have dependencies on DLLs in this directory.
  WCHAR current_directory[MAX_PATH] = {0};
  bool restore_directory = false;

  // THIS IS NOT THE PROPER WAY TO CONVERT A std::string TO A std::wstring!
  // This only works properly for ASCII strings.  You need to use
  // MultiByteToWideChar() or std::wstring_convert or other equivalent
  // to convert ANSI data to UNICODE data.  Otherwise, library_path should
  // be passed as a std::wstring to begin with...
  //
  std::wstring lp = std::wstring(library_path.begin(), library_path.end());

  std::wstring plugin_path, plugin_value;    
  const wchar_t *res = wcsrchr(lp.c_str(), L'\\');
  if (res)
  {
    plugin_path.assign(lp.c_str(), res);
    plugin_value.assign(++res);

    if (!plugin_path.empty())
    {
      GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, current_directory);
      restore_directory = SetCurrentDirectoryW(plugin_path.c_str());
    }
  }
  else
    plugin_value = lp;

  HMODULE module = (*load_library_api)(plugin_value.c_str());
  if (!module && error) {
    // GetLastError() needs to be called immediately after |load_library_api|.
    error->code = GetLastError();
  }

  if (restore_directory)
    SetCurrentDirectoryW(current_directory);

  return module;
}

...

NativeLibrary LoadNativeLibraryDynamically(const std::string& library_path) {
  LoadLibraryFunction load_library;
  load_library = reinterpret_cast<LoadLibraryFunction>(
      GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW"));

  return LoadNativeLibraryHelper(library_path, load_library, NULL);
}
```

That being said, DO NOT use `SetCurrentDirectory()` to influence where dependent DLLs are searched for!  The correct solution is to use [`SetDllDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203.aspx) (XP SP1+) or [`AddDllDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513.aspx) (Win8+) instead.

Using `SetDllDirectory()` only:

```
NativeLibrary LoadNativeLibraryHelper(const std::string& library_path,
                                      LoadLibraryFunction load_library_api,
                                      NativeLibraryLoadError* error) {
  // LoadLibrary() opens the file off disk.
  //ThreadRestrictions::AssertIOAllowed();

  // Include the library directory as the library may have dependencies on
  // DLLs in this directory.

  // THIS IS NOT THE PROPER WAY TO CONVERT A std::string TO A std::wstring!
  // This only works properly for ASCII strings.  You need to use
  // MultiByteToWideChar() or std::wstring_convert or other equivalent
  // to convert ANSI data to UNICODE data.  Otherwise, library_path should
  // be passed as a std::wstring to begin with...
  //
  std::wstring lp = std::wstring(library_path.begin(), library_path.end());

  std::wstring plugin_path, plugin_value;
  bool restore_old_order = false;

  const wchar_t *res = wcsrchr(lp.c_str(), L'\\');
  if (res)
  {
    plugin_path.assign(lp.c_str(), res);
    plugin_value.assign(++res);

    if (!plugin_path.empty())
      restore_old_order = SetDllDirectoryW(plugin_path.c_str());
  }
  else
    plugin_value = lp;

  HMODULE module = (*load_library_api)(plugin_value.c_str());
  if (!module && error) {
    // GetLastError() needs to be called immediately after |load_library_api|.
    error->code = GetLastError();
  }

  if (restore_old_order)
      SetDllDirectoryW(NULL);

  return module;
}
```

Using `AddDllDirectory()` only:

```
NativeLibrary LoadNativeLibraryHelper(const std::string& library_path,
                                      LoadLibraryFunction load_library_api,
                                      NativeLibraryLoadError* error) {
  // LoadLibrary() opens the file off disk.
  //ThreadRestrictions::AssertIOAllowed();

  // Include the library directory as the library may have dependencies on
  // DLLs in this directory.

  // THIS IS NOT THE PROPER WAY TO CONVERT A std::string TO A std::wstring!
  // This only works properly for ASCII strings.  You need to use
  // MultiByteToWideChar() or std::wstring_convert or other equivalent
  // to convert ANSI data to UNICODE data.  Otherwise, library_path should
  // be passed as a std::wstring to begin with...
  //
  std::wstring lp = std::wstring(library_path.begin(), library_path.end());

  std::wstring plugin_path, plugin_value;
  DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE cookie = 0;

  const wchar_t *res = wcsrchr(lp.c_str(), L'\\');
  if (res)
  {
    plugin_path.assign(lp.c_str(), res);
    plugin_value.assign(++res);

    if (!plugin_path.empty())
      cookie = AddDllDirectory(plugin_path.c_str());
  }
  else
    plugin_value = lp;

  HMODULE module = (*load_library_api)(plugin_value.c_str());
  if (!module && error) {
    // GetLastError() needs to be called immediately after |load_library_api|.
    error->code = GetLastError();
  }

  if (cookie)
    RemoveDllDirectory(cookie);

  return module;
}
```

Using whichever one is actually available at runtime:

```
NativeLibrary LoadNativeLibraryHelper(const std::string& library_path,
                                      LoadLibraryFunction load_library_api,
                                      NativeLibraryLoadError* error) {

  // LoadLibrary() opens the file off disk.
  //ThreadRestrictions::AssertIOAllowed();

  // Include the library directory as the library may have dependencies on
  // DLLs in this directory.

  typedef BOOL (WINAPI* SetDllDirectoryFunction)(LPCWSTR lpPathName);
  typedef PVOID DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE;
  typedef DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE (WINAPI* AddDllDirectoryFunction)(PCWSTR NewDirectory);
  typedef BOOL(WINAPI* RemoveDllDirectoryFunction)(DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE Cookie);

  HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32.dll");

  AddDllDirectoryFunction add_dll_directory;
  add_dll_directory = reinterpret_cast<AddDllDirectoryFunction>(
    GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "AddDllDirectory"));

  RemoveDllDirectoryFunction remove_dll_directory;
  if (add_dll_directory)
  {
    remove_dll_directory = reinterpret_cast<RemoveDllDirectoryFunction>(
      GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "RemoveDllDirectory"));
  }
  else
    remove_dll_directory = NULL;

  SetDllDirectoryFunction set_dll_directory;
  if (!(add_dll_directory && remove_dll_directory))
  {
    set_dll_directory = reinterpret_cast<SetDllDirectoryFunction>(
      GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "SetDllDirectoryW"));
  }
  else
    set_dll_directory = NULL;

  // THIS IS NOT THE PROPER WAY TO CONVERT A std::string TO A std::wstring!
  // This only works properly for ASCII strings.  You need to use
  // MultiByteToWideChar() or std::wstring_convert or other equivalent
  // to convert ANSI data to UNICODE data.  Otherwise, library_path should
  // be passed as a std::wstring to begin with...
  //
  std::wstring lp = std::wstring(library_path.begin(), library_path.end());

  DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE cookie = 0;
  bool restore_old_order = false;
  std::wstring current_directory;

  std::wstring plugin_path, plugin_value;

  const wchar_t *res = wcsrchr(lp.c_str(), L'\\');
  if (res)
  {
    plugin_path.assign(lp.c_str(), res);
    plugin_value.assign(++res);

    if (!plugin_path.empty())
    {
      if (add_dll_directory && remove_dll_directory)
        cookie = (*add_dll_directory)(plugin_path.c_str());
      else if (set_dll_directory)
        restore_old_order = (*set_dll_directory)(plugin_path.c_str());
      else
      {
        current_directory.resize(MAX_PATH);
        GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, &current_directory[0]);
        if (!SetCurrentDirectoryW(plugin_path.c_str()))
          current_directory.clear();
      }
    }
  }
  else
    plugin_value = lp;

  HMODULE module = (*load_library_api)(plugin_value.c_str());
  if (!module && error) {
    // GetLastError() needs to be called immediately after |load_library_api|.
    error->code = GetLastError();
  }

  if (remove_dll_directory)
  {
    if (cookie)
      (*remove_dll_directory)(cookie);
  }
  else if (set_dll_directory)
  {
    if (restore_old_order)
      (*set_dll_directory)(NULL);
  }
  else if (!current_directory.empty())
    SetCurrentDirectoryW(current_directory.c_str());

  return module;
}
```